# QML signal QT slot with QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qml, slot

Hello I have problem with connect QML signal with Qt slot when I use QQuickView here is my main.cpp:

```
ModelValueReceivers *mvr;
mvr = new ModelValueReceivers();
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl(("qrc:///Main.qml")));
QQuickView loginScreenView;
loginScreenView.setSource(QUrl(("qrc:///LoginScreen.qml")));
QObject *loginScreen = loginScreenView.rootObject();
QObject::connect(loginScreen, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString, int)), mvr->valuesReceivers[U1], SLOT(start(QString, int)));
view.show()
```

In ModelValueReceivers is slot public slots:
    `void start(QString ipAddress, int tcpPort);`

In LoginScreen.qml I have signal:
`signal qmlSignal(string addressIP, int portTCP)`

and emit is onClicked

```
onClicked: {
            console.log("onClicked");
            qmlSignal(ipTextField.text , parseInt(tcpPortTextField.text))
        }
```

In console I can see log "onClicked" but the slot doesn't start.

in Main.qml I have:

```
Rectangle {
id: screen; width: 320; height: 480;
color: "#ffffff"
StackView{
    id: sv
    property StackView sv: sv 
    initialItem: Qt.resolvedUrl("qrc:///LoginScreen.qml");
} }`
```

Comment: Ok to simplier example i give this:
`QObject::connect(loginScreen, SIGNAL(exitApp()), &ctrl, SLOT(on_closeAppButton_clicked()));`
I have slot int ctrl and the same signal in qml file

Comment: Oh, I got it. Than the sample is not sufficient. We don't know what kind of receiver is that. And no question!

Comment: I have main.qml where InitialItem is LoginScreen in LoginScreen i have button Login which should be connected to slot in Qt class, but i don't know how in main.cpp get connect LoginScreen signal with Qt class slot.

Comment: We cannot see in ModelValueReceivers and we don't know how the slot is defined.

Comment: Do you really have the signal `qmlSignal` in the root object in `LoginScreen.qml` or that signal is emited from some child object? Do you see some debug warnings?

Comment: Yes the signal is in 
`Rectangle{
    qmlSignal(ipTextField.text , parseInt(tcpPortTextField.text))
    .
    .
    .
    Button{
    .
    .
    onClicked{
       qmlSignal(ipTextField.text , parseInt(tcpPortTextField.text))
}}}`

I don't get error and warning it just run but the slot doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I already have done it with TabView and every view/file insert into separate tab, so now I have access to all tabs from Main. There is the example: [TabView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-tabviewstyle.html)

Insert file to tab : `component: Qt.createComponent("qrc:///LoginScreen.qml")`

In main.cpp I add: `QQmlContext* ctx = view.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("controller", &ctrl);`
and in every qml file I can connect signal QML to Qt Slot and Qt Signal to Qml Slot:

```
Connections{
target: controller
onSendValue:{
    u1TextField.text=String(value)

    }
}



onClicked: {
            console.log("Button Clicked")
            controller.on_closeAppButton_clicked()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless `LoginScreen.qml` is a singleton, I think, you are using 2 different objects of `LoginScreen.qml`, one in `main.cpp` and other in your `Main.qml`.

---

**Update**:

May be, you could do this:

Main.qml

```
...
signal signalFromLogin(string, int);

property Component loginScreen : LoginScreen {
   onQmlSignal: signalFromLogin(addressIP, portTCP);
}
StackView{
  id: sv
  property StackView sv: sv 
  initialItem: loginScreen;
}
```

now, in your `main.cpp`

```
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl(("qrc:///Main.qml")));
QObject* mainScreen = view.rootObject();
QObject::connect(maininScreen, SIGNAL(signalFromLogin(QString, int)), mvr->valuesReceivers[U1], SLOT(start(QString, int)));
```

please note, I have not tested this code.

Comment: So how can i connect signal from LoginScreen which is inside Main.qml

Comment: @Szymson check my update. this is not guaranteed to work. Still not sure about this `mvr->valuesReceivers[U1]`.

Comment: Inside mvr I have map ValuesReceivers[enum] which contains QTcpSocket and slot start(QString, int). This is working in my Qt app with MainWindow.cpp. Now i need to make qml GUI.

Comment: are you following this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html?

Comment: Yes i use the last sample on this page. It is working when i have qmlSignal in Main page but when I have signal in other it doesn't